# Insert a new row in an SQL table without assigning any values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an SSMS table that has one column that is a pk and set to auto increment. In my code I need to create a row and then pull the value of the ID.

I don't want to set the id, it needs to auto generate. Is there a way to do this without adding a second column to add data into?

Comment: your pk is already identity column?

Comment: Sounds like you should use a sequence instead.

Comment: Yes. The PK is already the identity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the phrase "DEFAULT VALUES" in place of a field list and values specification:

```
INSERT INTO [TableName] DEFAULT VALUES;
```

Test with:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
   ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO #Test DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

For more info on this, check out the MSDN page for [INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) and do a "find" (i.e. Control-F) in your browser for "default values".

Comment: Oh, brilliant.  Thank you. I kept getting an error when trying to do that earlier because I assigned which column I was using. Thanks again!